# ios json not working when using include()

Tags: php, ios, json

I have an app that receives a JSON file generated by my jason.php script and displays the data in a table view.

It works fine until I try to use 'include(db_connect.php)' in my jason.php file to pass the database log in details to it.

Running my php script, with 'include(db_connect.php)', *does* work in a browser (returns the JSON file formatted correctly) but it *doesn’t* work on my phone.

However..

It does work on my phone if I  just paste the contents of db_connect.php into  the jason.php file...and it returns exactly the same JSON file in a browser.

Both ways return exactly the same JSON text in browser.

All the app does is expect to receive a JSON file from a specified URL, it does’t pass anything to it. Just visits the URL and stores whats returned in an NSData object.

If anyone knows why this is happening I would be grateful to know!

Thanks

**jason.php:** *this returns a the JSON script perfectly in my browser*

```
<?php

require("db_connect.php");


//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cities";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }


}


?>
```

---

**db_connect.php** *the log in details*

```
  <?php 
    $host = "xxxxx"; //Your database host server
    $db = "xxxxx"; //Your database name
    $user = "xxxxx"; //Your database user
    $pass = "xxxxx"; //Your password
    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 ?>
```

---

**jason_pasted.php** this is exactly the same as jason.php but the contents of db_connect.php are just pasted in - produces exactly the same result in browser, and also works when used in my app.

```
<?php

$host = "xxxxx"; //Your database host server
$db = "xxxxxx"; //Your database name
$user = "xxxxx"; //Your database user
$pass = "xxxxxx"; //Your password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);


//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cities";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }


}


?>
```

---

**ViewController.m** *extract from the app code*

```
    -(void) retrieveData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //set up cities array
    citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0;i<[json count]; i++)
    {
        //create city object
        NSString *cID = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *cName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
        NSString *cState = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityState"];
        NSString *cPopulation = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityPopulation"];
        NSString *cCountry = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"country"];

        City *myCity = [[City alloc] initWithCityID:cID
                                        andCityName:cName
                                       andCityState:cState
                                  andCityPopulation:cPopulation
                                     andCityCountry:cCountry];

        //add city oject to city array
        [citiesArray addObject:myCity];

    }

    [davesTableView reloadData];


}
```

TL;DR the app works perfectly with jason_pasted.php but not jason.php.
jason.php and jason_pasted.php return exactly the same JSON script when opened in a browser.

---

**String returned from jason.php and jason_pasted.php**

```
(
    {
    cityName = London;
    cityPopulation = 8173194;
    cityState = London;
    country = "United Kingdom";
    id = 1;
},
    {
    cityName = Bombay;
    cityPopulation = 12478447;
    cityState = Maharashtra;
    country = India;
    id = 2;
},
    {
    cityName = "Kuala Lumpur";
    cityPopulation = 1627172;
    cityState = "Federal Territory";
    country = Malaysia;
    id = 3;
},
    {
    cityName = "New York";
    cityPopulation = 8336697;
    cityState = "New York";
    country = "United States";
    id = 4;
},
    {
    cityName = Berlin;
    cityPopulation = 3538652;
    cityState = Berlin;
    country = Deutschland;
    id = 5;
}
)
```

---

**error returned only when NSUrl points to jason.php**

```
    2014-02-13 11:43:34.760 JSONios[4655:60b] JSON error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
 object and option to allow fragments not set.) 
UserInfo=0x14659c40 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is placed in an answer for formatting:

Do not ignore errors!

Incorrect:

```
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Note: The docs do not specify that nil may be passed for the `error` parameter.

Correct:

```
// There is an assumption that the JSON head is a dictionary.
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonAsDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonAsDict == nil) {
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
}
else { // For debug only
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonAsDict);
}
```

Now, what happens with this code?
Also please provide the JSON string if possible.
Oh, I personally to not care how the php creates the JSON, all I need to see is the JSON.

Still having trouble: `NSLog` the data as a string:

```
NSLog(@"data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

If no data add the error parameter to 
`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`
in place of `dataWithContentsOfURL:`

Comment: Hi Zaph, thanks so much for your input. I've added the string outputed from jason.php and jason_pasted.php. They are both identical. My app runs fine when NSUrl points to jason_pasted.php and returns the same JSON script as from the browser when it is printed out from `NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonAsDict);` I have also added the error returned when the NSUrl points to jason.php (who's only difference is passing in the sever log in details using `'include(db_connect.php)'`)